# ¿Como entender el problema que me marcan de un código que parece funcionar sobre POO python, retornando enviar ,True , False y me da incorrecto?

Tags: python, poo, funciones, condiciones, python-3.7

> Estas trabajando para una empresa de envio de encomiendas. Para eso debes de escribir un
> codigo ya existente. el codigo tiene la siguiente clase ya
> implementada:

```
class Envio:
def __init__(self, emisor, receptor):
    self.emisor = emisor
    self.receptor = receptor
def enviar(self):
    pass
```

> El método enviar de la clase Envio se conecta directamente con la empresa de encomiendas y
> se encarga del despacho. No sabes como funciona este metodo , pero
> sabes que esta implementado correctamente y funciona. Deberas definir
> la clase Carta que herede Envio . esta clase tiene los siguientes
> metodos :
> *init*_(self, emisor, receptor): método que hace como mínimo lo mismo que el **init** de
> Envio

.

> poner_estampilla(self): este método no recibe parámetros, pero al llamarse coloca una
> estampilla en la carta
>
> enviar(self): este método deberá revisar que la carta tenga una estampilla y luego enviar
> correctamente con el método definido en Envio. Si la carta no tiene
> estampilla, entonces NO se deberá enviar. Finalmente, la función
> deberá retornar True si se envia la Carta y False en caso contrario.
>
> A continuación pongo el código que hice ...

```
class Carta(Envio):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor):
        super().__init__(emisor,receptor)
        self.tieneEstampilla = False

    def poner_estampilla(self):
        self.tieneEstampilla =  True

    def enviar(self):
        if  self.tieneEstampilla:
            super().enviar()
            return True
        else:
        return False
    mi_carta = Carta("Dario", "Romina")
    mi_carta.poner_estampilla()
    mi_carta.enviar()
```

> Me dice que es incorrecto y me da los siguientes ejemplos,pero no se que es lo que falla.
>
> INCORRECTO:

```
c0 = Carta('Gastón', 'David')
c0.poner_estampilla()
c0.enviar()
c0.enviar()

c1 = Carta('David', 'Gastón')
c1.enviar()
c1.poner_estampilla()
c1.enviar()
c1.enviar()

c2 = Carta('Elliot', 'Bob')
c2.poner_estampilla()
c2.enviar()

c3 = Carta('Gastón', 'Alicia')
c3.enviar()
c3.poner_estampilla()
c3.enviar()

c4 = Carta('Carlos', 'Alicia')
c4.poner_estampilla()
c4.enviar()
c4.enviar()

c5 = Carta('David', 'Elliot')
c5.poner_estampilla()
c5.enviar()
c5.enviar()

c6 = Carta('Carlos', 'Elliot')
c6.poner_estampilla()
c6.enviar()
c6.enviar()

c7 = Carta('David', 'Gastón')
c7.enviar()
c7.enviar()

c8 = Carta('Alicia', 'Francisca')
c8.enviar()
c8.poner_estampilla()
c8.enviar()

c9 = Carta('Elliot', 'David')
c9.enviar()
c9.enviar()
c9.enviar()

c10 = Carta('Francisca', 'Gastón')
c10.enviar()
```

```
> Tu respuesta:
> # Juan ha enviado Carta a Marcelo
> # Gastón ha enviado Carta a David
> # Gastón ha enviado Carta a David
> # David ha enviado Carta a Gastón
> # David ha enviado Carta a Gastón
> # Elliot ha enviado Carta a Bob
> # Gastón ha enviado Carta a Alicia
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Alicia
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Alicia
> # David ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # David ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # Alicia ha enviado Carta a Francisca
> # ----- 
> #  Los envios fueron correctos
> # \Respuesta esperada:
> # Gastón ha enviado Carta a David
> # Gastón ha enviado Carta a David
> # David ha enviado Carta a Gastón
> # David ha enviado Carta a Gastón
> # Elliot ha enviado Carta a Bob
> # Gastón ha enviado Carta a Alicia
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Alicia
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Alicia
> # David ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # David ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # Carlos ha enviado Carta a Elliot
> # Alicia ha enviado Carta a Francisca
> # ----- 
> #  Los envios fueron correctos
```

Comment: Quienes son Juan y Marcelo? Esta permitido que una carta pueda enviarse dos veces seguidas?

Comment: Omití a juan y marcos.Quedaron por error. Lease Dario , Romina. Y si , en este código no se restringen los envíos a un solo envió

Comment: Las salidas parecen idénticas, excepto la primera línea de "Juan...a Marcelo". Esa debe ser la diferencia, de hecho, es la única. Si el tester se basa en la salida, debiera decir que está bien.

Answer (score 0):

En la primera parte del problema, pusiste:

```
class Envio:
    def __init__( self, emisor, receptor ):
        self.emisor = emisor
        self.receptor = receptor

    def enviar( self ):
        return  'enviar la carta de ' + self.emisor, 'a' + self.receptor
```

ahora es:

```
class Envio:    
    def __init__( self, emisor, receptor ):
        self.emisor = emisor
        self.receptor = receptor
    def enviar( self ):
        pass
```

Nosotros desde la función `enviar` de la clase `Carta`, invocamos a `enviar` de `Envio`, y funcionaba, imprimía el mensaje correspondiente, (***aunque faltaba que devolviera `True`***).
Con la nueva función `enviar` es obvio que no va a hacer nada.
Tienes dos opciones, o re-escribes la función  `enviar` de `Carta` y le agregas el código de la otra, y descartas el `super`, o vuelves el `enviar` de `Envio` a su forma anterior (si es que esto está dentro de tu código).
O sea, en código, o bien:

```
class Envio:
    def __init__( self, emisor, receptor ):
        self.emisor = emisor
        self.receptor = receptor

    def enviar( self ):
        print(  'enviar la carta de ' + self.emisor, ' a ' + self.receptor )
        return  True
```

O bien:

```py
class Carta( Envio ):
    def __init__( self, emisor, receptor ):
        super().__init__( emisor,receptor )
        self.tieneEstampilla = False

    def poner_estampilla( self ):
        self.tieneEstampilla =  True

    def enviar( self ):
        if  self.tieneEstampilla:
            print( 'enviar la carta de ' + self.emisor, ' a ' + self.receptor )           
            return True
        else:
            # acá corregí un error de identación, que seguro se generó cuando copiaste 
            # la pregunta al sitio
            return False
```

Me voy a poner un poco pesado, tu profe usa mal la POO.
Nunca se lo digas si quieres aprobar, pero es importante que tú lo entiendas.
Con este código, estamos sobre-escribiendo la función `enviar`.
Las funciones se sobre-escriben, cuando se necesita un funcionamiento diferente.
Típico ejemplo: la clase `Figura` de la que heredan `Triangulo` y `Rectangulo`, ambas heredan la función `getArea` pero la implementan de distintas formas, para lo que la sobre-escriben.
El escenario es distinto al actual, donde la clase `Carta` usa la misma función `enviar` que la clase `Telegrama` o `SeñalesDeHumo`, no debe haber sobre-escritura todos usan esto:

```
def enviar( self ):
    print(  'enviar la carta de ' + self.emisor, ' a ' + self.receptor )
    return  True
```

función que heredan de `Envio`, por lo que lo lógico y lo que no haremos para que apruebes, es renombrar el `envio` de `Carta` a `prepararEnvio` (o el que más te agrade)...
Si quieres pensarlo desde otro lugar, elimina la función `enviar` de `Envio`, quita la llamada a `super` y verás que funciona igual.
Entonces, ¿para qué escribimos la función?
Espero que te haya quedado claro.