# ¿Cómo realizar una sumatoria en tipos propios en python?

Tags: python, poo, funciones, herencia, override

Me enfrentó al siguiente problema:

Una empresa de paquetería me indica que parta del siguiente código preexístete:

```
class Envio:
def __init__(self, emisor, receptor):
    self.emisor = emisor
    self.receptor = receptor

def enviar(self):
    pass
```

El método enviar de la clase Envio no se sabe cómo opera, pero funciona correctamente.

A partir de este código debo definir la clase Paquete que herede de Envio. Esta clase debe tener los siguientes métodos:

- `__init__(self,emisor,receptor,max_volumen)`. Cuando se crea el paquete este está inicialmente abierto, donde max_volumen es el volumen máximo que puede guardar el paquete.
- `agregar_producto (self,peso,volumen)`: este método se llama para agregar un producto al paquete. Este método recibe como parámetros el peso y el volumen que tiene el producto que se quiere agregar. Si la caja está cerrada, entonces se deberá abrir para que se pueda agregar el producto.
- `cerrar (self)`: método que no recibe parámetros. Este método se llama cuando se quiere cerrar el paquete. El paquete se deberá cerrar solamente si el volumen de todos los productos dentro del paquete es menos que el volumen máximo de la caja, en caso contrario la caja NO se deberá cerrar.
- `enviar ( self )`: método que no recibe parámetros. Este método se llama cuando se quiere enviar el paquete. El método deberá enviar el paquete utilizando el método enviar de Envio solamente si el paquete está cerrado y el peso de todos los productos dentro del paquete es menor o igual a 30. En caso contrario NO se deberá enviar el paquete. Finalmente, la función deberá retornar True si se envía el paquete y False en caso contrario.

El código que hice fue el siguiente:

```
class Paquete(Envio):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor, max_volumen):
        self.emisor = emisor
        self.receptor = receptor
        self.max_volumen = max_volumen
        self.volumen=0
        self.peso=0
        self.abierto = True
        self.enviado = False         

    def agregar_producto(self, peso, volumen):
        self.peso=peso
        self.volumen=volumen
        self.abierto is True          
            
    def cerrar(self):
        if self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:
            return self.abierto is False
        else:
            return self.abierto is True
        
    def enviar(self):
        if self.abierto is False and self.peso <= 30 and self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:  
            Envio.enviar(self)
            self.enviado=True
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Para corroborar el funcionamiento de mi código me piden que lo ponga aprueba con los siguientes casos:

```
p = Paquete('Gastón', 'David', 30)
p.enviar()
p.agregar_producto(10, 13)
p.agregar_producto(13, 9)
p.cerrar()
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Elliot', 'Bob', 38)
p.agregar_producto(8, 13)
p.agregar_producto(7, 11)
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Carlos', 'Alicia', 31)
p.enviar()
p.agregar_producto(11, 7)
p.agregar_producto(9, 10)
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Elliot', 'David', 37)
p.enviar()
p.agregar_producto(13, 11)
p.cerrar()
p.agregar_producto(9, 10)
p.agregar_producto(7, 9)
p.cerrar()
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Elliot', 'David', 35)
p.agregar_producto(12, 13)
p.agregar_producto(7, 8)
p.cerrar()
p.agregar_producto(10, 5)
p.agregar_producto(10, 8)
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Alicia', 'Alicia', 35)
p.enviar()
p.agregar_producto(9, 11)
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Elliot', 'Carlos', 38)
p.agregar_producto(10, 7)
p.agregar_producto(11, 13)
p.cerrar()
p.enviar()

p = Paquete('Elliot', 'Bob', 34)
p.agregar_producto(13, 8)
p.cerrar()
p.agregar_producto(7, 4)
p.agregar_producto(4, 9)
p.agregar_producto(10, 5)
p.cerrar()
p.enviar()
```

Mí código me arroja que ninguno de los paquetes se envía, es decir, False en todos, pero la respuesta esperada es que los casos

```
p = Paquete('Gastón', 'David', 30)
p = Paquete('Elliot', 'David', 37)
p = Paquete('Elliot', 'Carlos', 38)
```

Se envíen o sean iguales a `True`.

Me parece que el problema de mí código está en `def agregar_producto` (ya que no suma ni el peso ni el volumen sino lo sobreescribe) y en el momento en el que cierra el paquete pero no estoy seguro de cómo corregirlo.

De antemano les doy las gracias por cualquier orientación.

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/598135/171630) hay otro usuario con la misma tarea, hagan equipo e investiguen juntos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con el código que publicas en tu pregunta.

1. La clase `Envio` está mal indentada. En python la indentación es elemental, por lo que el interprete dará un error y no sería capaz de procesar ese código.
2. En el método `__init__` de la clase `Paquete` no hace falta repetir lo que ya hace el `__init__` de la clase envío. Una de las ideas de la herencia es ir construyendo sobre las clases de base, por lo que en lugar de estas dos líneas:

   ```
   self.emisor = emisor
   self.receptor = receptor
   ```

   Es mejor agregar la llamada

   ```
   super().__init__(emisor, receptor)
   ```

   En esta clase el trabajo es trivial, aún así, una implementación posterior podría hacer más cosas y, por otro lado, en la vida real, solemos heredar de clases que hacen muchas más cosas en su inicialización y por muchas razones, no vamos a re-escribir ese código en cada descendiente. (Principio DRY).
3. En varias partes estás utilizando el operador `is` como si se tratase del signo de igualdad, pero `is` sirve para comparar si dos variables son el mismo objeto. En general se utiliza el operador de igualdad `==` para realizar comparaciones de igualdad y, en el caso de variables booleanas, muchas veces resulta innecesario comparar. Por ejemplo, siendo `miVariable` un valor booleano:

   ```
   if miVariable == True:
   ```

   es exactamente igual a poner solamente

   ```
   if miVariable:
   ```
4. Estás mezclando la comparación de valores a una variable con el retorno de una función y no creo que tengas claro lo que realmente estás haciendo. Es mejor mantener las cosas más simples y hacer las comparaciones por un lado y el retorno de valores por otro.

   Por ejemplo, no sé bien que pretendes con esta línea:

   ```
   return self.abierto is False
   ```

   Que es equivalente a esta otra expresión más compleja, pero probablemente más legible:

   ```
   if self.abierto is False:
       return True
   else
       return False
   ```

   Además de lo que ya comenté sobre el operador `is`, no creo que sea lo que quieres hacer.
5. Mencionas qué llamadas del código de prueba debieran resultar satisfactorias, pero no hay una llamada a `p = Paquete('Elliot', 'Carlos', 38)` en dicho código, por lo que es imposible que dé el resultado que quieres.
6. Aunque la descripción del problema no lo menciona, hay varias validaciones adicionales que convendría hacer. Por ejemplo, para agregar un producto, habría que hacerlo solo si el paquete no se ha enviado.
7. Las especificaciones piden un valor de retorno solamente en el método `Enviar()` y no en los otros, pero tú si estás agregando uno en todos. Esto no es necesario.
8. Finalmente, las instrucciones son bastante sencillas, casi, casi, se puede escribir el código con solo leerlas, a mi me queda algo como:

```
class Paquete(Envio):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor, max_volumen):
        super().__init__(emisor, receptor)
        self.max_volumen = max_volumen
        self.volumen=0
        self.peso=0
        self.abierto = True

    def agregar_producto(self, peso, volumen):
        self.abierto = True;
        self.peso += peso
        self.volumen += volumen

    def cerrar(self):
        if self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:
            self.abierto = False

    def enviar(self):
        if self.abierto or (self.peso > 30):
            return False
        else:
            super().enviar()
            return True
```

A estas alturas, puedes solo copiar y pegar el código para obtener un 100 en la tarea. Mi recomendación es que no lo hagas. Lee la explicación que te he dado para cada uno de los problemas, estudia el código de la respuesta y trata de producir tu propia solución al problema, si realmente tienes interés de aprender, es la ruta a seguir.

Comment: Para profundizar por que no usar is como comparador de igualdad: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/158880

Comment: Muchas gracias jachguate en primer lugar por ayudarme a resolver el problema, y en segundo lugar (y sobre todo) por toda la retroalimentación y las observaciones que me hiciste, ya que en última instancia gracias al estudio de las mismas podré solucionar cuestiones que vayan más allá de la resolución de este problema en específico.

Comment: Gracias Dante S. por el enlace para profundizar en el estudio del uso de is para comparar valores.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene unos problemines...

```
 def agregar_producto( self, peso, volumen ):

       # sumamos el valor ingresado al contenido
    self.peso = self.peso + peso
    self.volumen = self.volumen + volumen
    self.abierto is True    
        
def cerrar( self ):
    if self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:

           # reemplazamos el "return self.abierto is False" por
        self.abierto = False
        return True
    else:

           # reemplazamos el "return self.abierto is True" por
        self.abierto = True
        return False
```

Con estas simples modificaciones, ya estamos en carrera.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con las modificaciones el código corrió perfecto.

Comment: Un placer maestro!